# Undefined method `emails' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an issue with the below code in one of my views:

```
<% if !@admin.emails.nil? %>
<% @admin.emails.each do |email| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= email.email %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

This produces an error:

```
undefined method `emails' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <% @admin.emails.each do |email| %>
2:   <tr>
3:     <td><%= email.email %></td>
4:   </tr>
```

Admin Controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
end
def index
      @emails = Email.all
      respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.xml  { render :xml => @emails }
     end
end
```

Email Model:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
  belongs_to :admin
  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :length     => { :maximum => 250 },
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

end
```

Admin Model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails
end
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Where are you defining `@admin`?

Comment: Crap i'm not. I'm trying to show a list of emails in an admin view. Admin is currently just a static page. How should I define?

Comment: You are defining `@emails` so why not use that instead of `@admin.emails`?

Comment: Yep, combined with Chase's comment, that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index method is not inside the AdminController... :)

And it defines `@emails` rather than `@admin`.